# SOLR sqlserver unable to execute query

Tags: java, sql-server, solr

I'm attempting to setup SOLR for the sake of indexing a few large tables and allow faster text searches. 
When trying to import, I get the error "Unable to execute query"
Here is what's currently in my dataconfig file:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=tempdb" readOnly="True" user="TestSA" password="testtest"/>
<document>
    <entity name="testTable" query="select * from TestTable">
        <field column="id" name="id" />
        <field column="Test" name="test" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

The solrconfig.xml file is identical to that of the example one only that I've added:

```
     <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="sqljdbc42\.jar" /> 

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

(Note that the sqljdbc42.jar file had been copied to the dist/ folder.

I'm at a complete loss as to why I'm getting this error.

Here's the log I receive:

```
    Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select * from TestTable Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:270)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:415)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:474)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.lambda$runAsync$0(DataImporter.java:457)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$$Lambda$176/1884110365.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select * from TestTable Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:329)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select * from TestTable Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:327)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.createResultSetIterator(JdbcDataSource.java:288)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:283)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:52)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:267)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.createStatement(JdbcDataSource.java:342)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:318)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: What port is the database server listening on?  It's unusual to not see a port in the connection URL. The default value is 1433.  It's common for an admin to change it.  I wonder if the real problem is that you never connected in the first place.  Look further down in the stack trace.

Comment: The default port is still being used (1433). 
Though looking further down the stack trace I see "Login failed for user 'TestSA'."
Thanks, I'll poke at this and see if I can get it working and report back

Answer (score 0):

The username did not have access.
I managed to miss the "Failed login" and jumped the gun here.

Thanks